# How to reset php srand function count?

Tags: php, floor, srand

I have the following instruction:

```
$seed = floor(time()/(60*1));
    srand($seed);
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $length = 8;
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
     }
```

I'll put this inside a function, but that's not the problem. Well, basically it will generate random code with 1 minute expiration.

I need that after triggering a `form` this 1 minute count is reset to generate a new code. That is, if the user completes a certain action within 1 minute of triggering a form, he must generate a new code and not use the same code that was generated.

When the `form` fires the data is sent, then the page is reloaded. At this time I need the code not to be the same as the one sent previously.

Is this possible?

**Update:** In fact, I'm going to increase this time to 10 minutes, which is enough time for the user to complete a certain action on the page. What I'm doing is generating a unique id to write to the database when the form is triggered, this unique id will be used to look for images that will have this id at the beginning of the filename. It's basically a product image upload system.

Comment: If the codes are just random, the only way I see is to save the generated in the cookies of the user. Whenever he reloads the page, keep generating random codes until is different from the current one. However I feel you are doing something complicated that could be solved with other solutions like a csrf token.

Answer (score 0):

> That is, if the user completes a certain action within 1 minute of triggering a form, he must generate a new code and not use the same code that was generated.

Do you mean if he **doesn't** complete the action within one minute? It sounds like you want the code to be valid for one minute only?

`$seed = floor(time()/(60*1));`

What's the purpose of (60 * 1) here?

Anyway, I'd not rely on rand() for purposes like this. Have a read of random_bytes() and see if that will fit your use case. Store the generated value and expiration as a session var or in the user's DB table (if there is one).

Comment: In fact, I'm going to increase this time to 10 minutes, which is enough time for the user to complete a certain action on the page. What I'm doing is generating a unique id to write to the database when the form is triggered, this unique id will be used to look for images that will have this id at the beginning of the filename.

Comment: Okay. I'd definitely use random_bytes() or something similar instead of the function in your original post. Use bin2hex(random_bytes(int x)) to get a readable string from the randomly generated bytes and store this in your DB along with a column that has the timestamp of when you ran INSERT. Presumably it's a per-user code, so have a foreign key column that refs the user.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you divide by (60*1)? It seems for one minute, but if you want different code for every triggering (within one minute), you can use millisecond or other random mechanisms

Comment: In fact, I'm going to increase this time to 10 minutes, which is enough time for the user to complete a certain action on the page. What I'm doing is generating a unique id to write to the database when the form is triggered, this unique id will be used to look for images that will have this id at the beginning of the filename. It's basically a product image upload system.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).